# is possible use external url in firebase hosting ajax or http requests?

Tags: node.js, ajax, firebase, firebase-hosting, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to know if the firebase can use external url:

defaultUrl:https://us-central1-ecc-local.cloudfunctions.net/getAjax

externalExampleUrl: https://externalurl.com/data.json

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://us-central1-ecc-local.cloudfunctions.net/getAjax',
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {startdate: 1505941200, enddate: 1506373200},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Got data", data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        console.log('status: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
    },
});
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLto75pe7IU

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting doesn't really care what JavaScript you're running in the web content it serves.  Its only responsibility is to deliver that content (HTML, JavaScript, CSS, images) to the browser.

If you're trying to access content from a different site than the one you've served from Firebase Hosting, then you will need to look into using CORS, so that the browser doesn't block the request.